# Render an image onto a pillow

Tags: python, image, image-processing, render

I want to make a program that takes in an image and renders that image onto a pillow (cushion). How do I go about this?

I tried following online tutorials (using the python pillow library) but all I learnt was to change the dimensions of the image. I tried looking for repos that do similar things but had no luck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What are your inputs? Do you have a mesh model of the pillow?

Comment: Yup, I have a mesh in a few formats: .blend, .obj, .fbx. The input image is a .jpg